# Can't connect with my django rest framework API with axios in react native

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm developing an application with React Native and I can't connect to my own API. I made a database with django rest framework and I'm trying to connect to it with axios. I'm receiving an error with "Network Error" message with the name "AxiosError". Here is the error (with error.toJSON()):

Object {
"code": "ERR_NETWORK",
"columnNumber": undefined,
"config": Object {
"adapter": [Function xhrAdapter],
"data": undefined,
"env": Object {
"FormData": null,
},
"headers": Object {
"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
},
"maxBodyLength": -1,
"maxContentLength": -1,
"method": "get",
"timeout": 0,
"transformRequest": Array [
[Function transformRequest],
],
"transformResponse": Array [
[Function transformResponse],
],
"transitional": Object {
"clarifyTimeoutError": false,
"forcedJSONParsing": true,
"silentJSONParsing": true,
},
"url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/usuario",
"validateStatus": [Function validateStatus],
"withCredentials": false,
"xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
"xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
},
"description": undefined,
"fileName": undefined,
"lineNumber": undefined,
"message": "Network Error",
"name": "AxiosError",
"number": undefined,
"stack": undefined,
"status": null,
}

Currently I'm doing it without authentification needed because i thought I should have less errores (tried it also with authentification earlier a lot and same error). This is my axios function:

```
try {
    const axios = require('axios');
    
    const students = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/usuario', {withCredentials: false});
    //const students = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    
    setPrueba(JSON.stringify(students.data));
```

The line commented is a API that gives a placeholder json, and it works fine, so i don't think it's an axios error. In order to avoid the authenthification I did this in my settings.py:
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [],
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [],

Also, when i call a request from Postman into my API I receive this correctly:

[Postman receiver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJJSK.png)

Any idea of a solution? I don't know how to continue or what is the problem... Sorry for my english and also for any trouble in the post (is my first one). Thank you.